# group design in eclipse 4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to add an image and a label in a group on a composite by using eclipse 4 RCP. Example image is like below. How can I do this?

[image: example image]

My example code is below:

```
Group group_incom = new Group(dynamicDataComp, SWT.NONE);
    group_incom.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
    group_incom.setText("Incom. Msg.");
    Label lbl_incomMsg = toolkit.createLabel(group_incom, "# of Incoming Messages : ", SWT.NONE);
    Image img = new Image(lbl_incomMsg.getDisplay(), "<path>");
    lbl_incomMsg.setImage(img);
    lbl_incomMsg.setLocation(15, 15);
    lbl_incomMsg.pack();
```

The problem is, I can see the image but I can not see the label text.

Comment: So have you tried `Group` ? What was the problem?

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label` can display text **or** an image, it won't display both. So either use two `Label` controls one for the image and one for the text or use `CLabel` which can display both.

Comment: I created a new label and added it into group. By this way my problem was solved. Thank you.